# UILabel string truncate

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, sdk

I have a problem, is there any way to truncate the text of a label without changing its' font-size?
Let's suppose a width of label is 200 and string size is more then 200, it will then squeeze the string and make it size to small to read.
I'm looking for a way to adjust the string length to 200 and truncate rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want the font size to be adjusted in order for the text to fit into the width of the label, you can set the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property of the label to `NO`.

See the [UILabel class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) for more information. You will also want to read about the `numberOfLines` and `lineBreakMode` properties, as they also affect how truncation of the text in a UILabel works.